# Protect Android Application From Moding

Tags: android, apk, android-security

We have a challenge that reverse engineer modding our App and change some behavior of it and repack it.

We added a App signature checking to code but the reverse engineer can found that part and disabled it.

the another challenge is the third-party API we use must done on client and we can't perform it on server.
Anyone have idea to increase security of App ?

Comment: add minify =true in gradle  and use proguard

Comment: Watch [Bulletproof Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yF5sqGJo90)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 3 things in mind for security.

1. use proguard for code deobfuscation
2. write native code for your secured part. It can't be reverse engineered
3. or process your secured part in server side & use the result.

Comment: thank you , I used proguard but the reverse engineer work on Smali code.

Comment: 2 is not feasible for general audience.